# rails and jquery post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, geolocation, jquery-post

im using this jquery post

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        $.post('/marketplace',{latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude})
      });
```

routes:

```
post '/marketplace' => 'pages#marketplace'
```

in controller `Rails.logger.debug('Jquery.POST' + params.inspect)` print in the console following

```
Started POST "/marketplace" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-20 13:23:16 +0300
  Processing by PagesController#marketplace as 
  Parameters: {"latitude"=>"44.508851", "longitude"=>"33.600509"}
Jquery.POST{"latitude"=>"44.508851", "longitude"=>"33.600509", "controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"marketplace"}
```

Also firebug says that latitude 44.508851 and longitude 33.600509 successfully sent.
But in the view i dont have my post data, `= params.inspect`

```
{"action"=>"marketplace", "controller"=>"pages"}
```

How to access my jquery post data in the controller?

*Update

```
@lat = request.params[:latitude]
@long = request.params[:longitude]
```

both nil in the view :(

Answer (score 0):

This will create xhr request.for that you have to create

```
@lat_long={:lat=>request.params[:latitude],:lng=>request.params[:longitude]}
render :text=> @lat_long and return false
```

use above line in your controller and in jquery

```
$.post('/marketplace',{latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude},function(data) {
   var lat=data.lat;
   var lng=data.lng
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an issue with the csrf token? Are you sure it's being sent along with the rest of your POST data?

If you're using the jquery-rails plugin, be sure to grab the latest version since there's been some changes with the way this is being handled. The plugin should automatically inject it into each xhr POST request if you've got the token in the `head` of your document. Check out [the github](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/) page for more info.

Comment: i update my rails.js, nothing changes. Rails debugger says that data exist in params, but when im trying to reach it, all what im get is nil. Im wonder maybe js post data comes to controller async, and view already rendered nil, while $.post data didnt come to controller yet?

Comment: douby about async, in rails log parameters passed with controller, dunno why i getting nil in the view :(